# Could two people fly on one broomstick?

Tags: harry-potter, flying-brooms

That's the question- could two people fly on the same broomstick together? Or would they be too heavy?

Comment: Agreed, this is discussed in the answer over there.

Comment: I don't people being "too heavy" is much of an issue where magic broomsticks are concerned.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo - Hagrid claimed to be too heavy.